# How can i get mod_rewrite and .htaccess working with cakephp?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get cakephp working locally on my mac - yosemite. I have apache and php working locally in my /~user/Sites directory... I can hit a php ini file ok and have an install of wordpress in another directory.

I've hooked it all up apart from getting the urls rewriting... I followed the steps on the cake site:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

Now all I get is 404 not found!.

The three .htaccess files have the default content with an additional RewriteBase pointing to the folder its installed in, in my Sites folder.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I've read the other posts on this and none of them helped!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm mod_rewrite is enabled by (on command line):

```
# a2enmod rewrite
```

If it just got enabled using the command above, restart apache:

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

These types of errors should hit your error.log .. while trying to load the site, hold the error log open:

```
# tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log
```

and try to access your page again.

If this doesn't help you solve the problem, paste in your rewrite rules so we can take a peak.